# WebRTC infintive voice loop

Tags: webrtc

When i start my webcam in WebRTC, sound is going to loop and very tiny voice starting.

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream){             
     window.localStream = stream;
     stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false; 
     stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
     $('#my-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
    }
```

This solution is disabling all audio. I just want to mute only "stream" audio not window.localSream so send audio remote.

Comment: have you tried `$('#my-video')[0].muted = true`

Comment: Yes i'v tried also that. Your and all ather solutions can mute voice not local microphone.
This problem can solve only disabling "Listen to this device" from Audio Card - Microphone.
So WebRTC not capable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "sound is going to loop and very tiny voice starting". Do you mean the voice is too low and you hear echoing?

In your code, the audio track is still in your localStream, but just not rendered by disabling it, so the other end user will not hear any voice from you, you can also turn it on on fly but enable it, and your voice will be heard again.

To not include audio at all, you will have to set your constraints like {audio: false, video: true}